# jQuery AJAX POST request resulting in Error 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf

I have created an AJAX-enabled WCF service using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace AJAX
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class CalculatorService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public int GetRandomNumber()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            return rand.Next(100);
        }

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public int Subtract(int a, int b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to make requests to the various methods using the following code:

```
function random() {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/CalculatorService.svc/GetRandomNumber",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonData) {
            var number = jsonData.d;
            alert(number);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
};

function add() {
    var inputData = {"a": 10, "b": 5};

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/CalculatorService.svc/Add",
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonData) {
            var number = jsonData.d;
            alert(number);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
};

function subtract() {
    var inputData = { "a": 10, "b": 5 };

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/CalculatorService.svc/Subtract",
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonData) {
            var number = jsonData.d;
            alert(number);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#randomNumberButton").click(function () {
        random();
    });

    $("#addButton").click(function () {
        add();
    });

    $("#subtractButton").click(function () {
        subtract();
    });
});
```

Now, for some strange reason, the **GetRandomNumber** request works perfectly.  However, for the **Add** and **Subtract** POST requests, I am getting an "Error 500: Internal Server Error" in the console.  How can I solve this problem please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the following line to each POST ajax request, everything works well.

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```